# Launching a cordova app from service

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I'm not an Android developer, but I made a Service extending from [bgs-core](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core), my problem is that I need re-open my app when it's closed.

The service works, but I need to relaunch the main activity, (I don't need it in foreground).

I tried the following code:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();                             
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

And it works, but there are two problems:

- It runs in a timer (every second the app is lauched)
- This force to launch in foreground

I need to know when the activity is close/destroyed.

The code of my service: https://paste.kde.org/pglfsnstb